# JQuery UI Model Dialog is clearing my radio buttons before the data can be submitted?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, jquery-ui-dialog

My JQueryUI model dialog has some radio buttons and input boxes so users can select a date range for downloading information.

The dialog was initailized with two buttons, Download and Cancel.  The Download button's function triggers an ASP.NET link button to submit by evaluating it's HREF property, then it calls "dialog('close')" to close the model dialog.

Problem is... the radio buttons for certain download options are cleared before the data gets submitted.

Why is the JQueryUI dialog clearing the radio buttons (but not the text fields?) when it closes?  It shouldn't be clearing anything IMO, that should be up to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was a bug in the version of jQuery I was using along with jQueryUI.  Updating to the latest version of jQuery made this issue disappear (going from 1.5.2 to 1.7.2).  Specifically, it had problem's restoring the state of reconstructed objects in the dialog.